# How to find out whether a map is conformal (for $e^{iz^2})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the complex map
$$z \mapsto w(z)=e^{iz^2}$$
How would one go about investigating its image, in e.g. the first quadrant $\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < \text{arg}(z)<\pi/2\rbrace$?
When is this map conformal? It is analytic for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, because it has a power expansion that converges everywhere, but how do I explicitly find where the map is invertible?

Comment: Do you mean "conformal" mapping?

Comment: The multivaluedness derives from the fact that $e^{z + 2\pi i} =e^{z}$. Thus, can you find when $z^2 = z'^2 + 2\pi$?

Comment: When It has series expansion $e^{iz^2}=1+iz^2-\frac12z^4+\cdots$ why it is not analytic?

Comment: @Maryam I guess you are right, I was confusing injectivity for surjectivity... So, it IS analytic but not confrontal everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the mapping $w(z)$ one-to-one, we need to restrict $z$ to some region of the complex plane.

The first thing is that two points $z$ and $z'$ are mapped on the same $w$, iff
$$ z^2 - z'^2 \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}; \tag{1}$$
this is the multi-valuedness of the $\exp$ function. So in order to keep $w$ single-valued, we want to have that 
$$0 <\operatorname{Re}(z^2) \leq 2\pi.\tag{2}$$

For $z$, we use the parameterization $z= r e^{i\phi}$. In order that $z^2$ is single-valued, we need to have that $0\leq \phi < \pi$ and $0<r$. We have that $\operatorname{Re}(z^2) = r^2 \cos(2\phi)$. The condition (2) leads to the constraints
$$ (\phi \in [0,\pi/4] \cup [3\pi/4, \pi) ) \quad \land\quad 0< r \leq \sqrt{2\pi/\cos(2\phi)}.$$

Comment: And this is a sufficient condition for the map to be conformal?

Comment: You have checked that the map is analytic. So the only thing to do is to find a region such that it is one-to-one.

Comment: is this a standard way to check if the map is one-to-one or is it highly dependant on the problem?

Comment: I don't know if this is standard...

Comment: Well, I guess it isn't a very standard question either... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why restrict the real part between 0 en 2pi, shouldn't it be the imaginary part?

Comment: It should be the imaginary part of $iz^2$ which is the real part of $z^2$.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for all your help.